# Rails: Query using relation or directly using #where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, coldfusion

I am from UI/ColdFusion background, sorry if I am asking a silly question.

Let's say we have two models `Book & Page` and a book has many pages.
Normally i see rails devs do the below,

```
book = Book.find(id)
pages = book.pages
```

Which indeed executes two queries, one for getting the book and one for getting the pages.

Where as the same we can write like this,

```
Add a class method to Page model. 
pages = Page.where(book_id: id)
```

This will execute one query but will still return the result.

But then why developers prefers the first approach instead of the second.

Comment: I feel the Question label **instance vs class method in rails** 

is bit confusing as per the actual question asked

Answer (score 2):

It's just the practice people follow

Usually, this scenario comes when you are accessing nested resources

```
book = Book.find(id)
pages = Page.where(book_id: id)
```

so to make sure you have the book available not just the orphan pages

```
pages = Page.where(book_id: id)
```

Whereas, with the above query you will get the pages even if the book is deleted, in case you don't have the `dependent: :destroy` for pages

Comment: May be its the rails way , but i am not too much satisfied , today I found a nested relation which was firing 5/6 queries sequentially , which i could have fetched using single sql statement. I am pretty surprised with the way activerecord works, unnecessarily it executes a lot of queries which will hit performance someday for sure.

Comment: I believe you must be talking about N+1 queries

Answer (score 2):

From my practice, there are 2 answers to your question and the right answer would depend on the developer's experience.

1. **Novice** - Because that's how it was in the tutorials. The first Rails team I joined had a lead developer with no DB or SQL experience. He would not care or knew about the load on db server our code generated. This was quite common in early days of Rails (in my experience). ActiveRecords makes it so easy to forget that you have a DB in the background and it is easy to forget. Coming from java and php world myself, I would be asking why would we just write an SQL to join and do the heavy lifting on the server side.
2. **Experienced** - Experienced developers do it for the code readability. Because maintaining a readable code is cheaper in the long run. If your monitoring tools show that your DB server started to stress out, you can always profile and fix it (vertical scaling, adding caches on different levels of your architecture, etc). Also, when used in the controller, `.find` will generate 404 page if it can't find the record in the DB. Also, if you run your "custom" sql, you will lose "automatic" model-data relation maintained by AR for you. So, many choose to just do it that way.

So there you go. Unless you are working on very heavy load application, it is better to write a readable way.